# Use python to identify table in HTML and then take a screenshot of it

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to take a screenshot of tables on HTML so that I can then publish them on Jupyter using markdown language.

The tables come from different websites and all have different formats, so it is easier for users to view the snapshot instead of looking at the print of the df.

I can find the tables using beautifulsoup and i can display the image once its saved on the PC but I don't know how to tell the PC to take a snapshot of that table (table[0] on each site) specifically.

Any help would be really appreciated!

This is the code i am using to identify the table:
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
for url in urls:

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Extract table using pandas
tables = pd.read_html(response.content)

# Assuming the desired table is the first one on the page
table = tables[0]

# Convert table to Markdown format
markdown_table = table.to_markdown(index=False)

# Print the Markdown table
print(url)
print(markdown_table)
```

This is the code I will use to print out the table snapshot using markdown language:

```
# Generate the Markdown syntax
markdown_syntax = f"![table-printout]({table_snapshot.png})"

# Display the Markdown syntax as formatted output
display(Markdown(markdown_syntax))
```

What I need is to find out how exactly to take a snapshot in png format of only the table. I can easily find the table in the code but it doesnt have an url that only shows the table.

Any help would really be appreciated!